# PHPExcel Sorting a sheet and create a new sheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Here is my situation.
I am having one excel sheet that contains 20000 records of different addresses.
The data is mapped like this

```
+----+---------+-------+-------+-----+
| Sr | Addr 1  |Addr 2 | State | zip |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-----+
```

This is the sample data mapping.
Now What I want is to create sub lists or sheets that are sorted according to specific column say Sheet 1 contains list sorted based on State column.

And sheet 2 sorted according to zip code.

How can I achieve this using PHPExcel Library?

Comment: what have you done and tried so far? Please provide your code

Comment: @DasSaffe I appreciate your concern, but the truth is I was so confused to try something so I asked question here for suggestions, will try and share the code if I face problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how much memory you have - I'd use the Worksheet's `toArray()` method to copy the cells from the main sheet to a PHP array, then you can use `usort()` to sort that array however you like, then create a new worksheet and use `fromArray()` to populate it with the sorted data - but for 20,000 rows, you need enough memory to hold that data as an array in memory.